# Svg Rotate and Resize issue

Tags: javascript, svg, resize, rotation

I am working in SVG and i am stuck in a scenerio, so i need some quick help. here is a working demo in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5ekCa/

**Issue**
I rotated a rectangle at some angle along its center, which work fine. Then i Shorten the Width of Rectangle and i rotate it again.This time it cause little false rotation. What i found is that its because of the new  center point of rectangle. how i solve this issue? rectangle must rotate along its New Center Point.

**Code:**

```
var rotate_rect = document.getElementById('rotate_rect');
var rectangle = document.getElementById('rectangle');
var angle = 0;

function calculateCenterXY(node) {
    var x = node.getBBox().x + (node.getBBox().width / 2);
    var y = node.getBBox().y + (node.getBBox().height / 2);

    var xy_co = {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };

    return xy_co;

}

function rotateMainRect() {

    var centxy = calculateCenterXY(rectangle);
    angle += 5;
    rotate_rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + angle + ',' + centxy.x + ',' + centxy.y + ')');


}

function decreaseRectsize() {
    var newRectWidth = 50;
    rectangle.setAttribute('width', newRectWidth);
}

function RestoreRectsize() {
    var newRectWidth = 100;
    rectangle.setAttribute('width', newRectWidth);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <svg id="mainSvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="350" height="300">
                <g id="rotate_rect">
                    <rect id="rectangle" x="50" y="100" width="100" height="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="black" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top">
            <button onclick="rotateMainRect()">Rotate +5 Angle</button>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top">
            <button onclick="decreaseRectsize()">Decrease Rect Size</button>
            <br/>
            <button onclick="RestoreRectsize()">Restore Rect Size</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*Note :-  In fiddle, before testing change Js load option to  'no wrap-in body

Answer (score 0):

The centre of the small rect is at a different position from the large rect. The small rect is effectively the left half of your big rect because you are only changing the width. When you resize the rect, you also need to reposition them so that their centres coincide.

```
function decreaseRectsize() {
    var newRectWidth = 50;
    rectangle.setAttribute('width', newRectWidth);
    rectangle.setAttribute('x', 75);
}

function RestoreRectsize() {
    var newRectWidth = 100;
    rectangle.setAttribute('width', newRectWidth);
    rectangle.setAttribute('x', 50);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. This is not what i am looking for. I am working on a project which require resizing of rectangle from one End. So i cannot change X or Y like you did above.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Soon i will upload complete solution with Demo.

Comment: @RashFlash I am facing the same problem. Can you share your solution please? Many thanks!